# Do any background walls allow teleporting back to ship?

Tags: starbound

It gets annoying that you can't teleport back to your ship from your house because of the background walls.

Are there any blocks that allow beaming up when used as the background?

Comment: Note: Background walls don't block teleports on Casual mode. Though that probably doesn't help you. Also probably a mod for it in Survival mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any background blocks that allow you to teleport while in Survival mode...but there's a Workshop mod called "EZs Beam Up For Survival" that will allow you to teleport regardless of the presence of background blocks. The mod can be found on Steam Workshop [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=742796011).

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few blocks, and even widows and fences block the Beam up, so I don't think there is a block that would allow it.

What you can do is remove the third block from the ground, and standing on it will allow you to beam up, you can also do this behind furniture, for example a book case or large wooden create so it will look like a closed room but you can teleport out.

[image: For example]

Comment: Note: any solution that involves gaps in the background wall will potentially allow monsters to spawn in that gap, even if you hide it with an object, somewhat defeating the purpose of having a wall in the first place.